# Data connection takes a long time to start up

Tags: mobile-data

My tablet has a SIM card that gets data over AT&T's cell network. Once the connection gets going it works great, but connecting to the network takes about 5 minutes. This is strange because it only takes a few seconds for the tablet to determine that it can detect the network at full strength; it just takes a long time for the little "H" to show up next to the signal-strength icon, at which point data exchange can occur.

What can I do to accelerate this? I'm running CyanogenMod on a Nexus 7 2012 tablet.

Comment: You can make sure you have the correct APN selected. I don't have AT&T so I don't know what one is correct, but I know with CM on my TMobile, when I installed CM12 I had to change the APN or I couldn't even get a data connection.

Comment: Just checked my settings against http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB424489&cv=820 and everything seems to match up.

Comment: Do you have many other APNs defined? Try deleting ones that you don't use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this issue to my local AT&T store and had them look at the tablet. They inspected my settings and said they were correct. I had them give me a new SIM card in hopes that would fix the problem; this seemed to lower the connection time somewhat, but it would still take several minutes.

Eventually I factory reset my tablet and switched from CyanogenMod back to stock Android. That made the problem go away; data connection time is back down to a couple seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Reason 1 :
H (HSDPA) signal requires greater strength and a mobile tower that emits 3G (HSDPA) signal. In your case ,the phone connects to a 2G mobile tower (near your vicinity) and then searches for a 3G signals ( maybe that tower is somewhere far)

Reason 2:
Cyanogenmod maybe designed in such a way that it first connects to 2G and then swithces to 3G. You might want to head on to their support page for further information.